# Unable to execute .cmd file in post build event command line

Tags: continuous-integration, automated-tests, build-automation, specflow

In my uitest project am able to execute .cmd file with RunAsAdmin but not with user and also tried giving admin permission to user but not succedded.
From the build process I need to execute .cmd file after build process. can any one help on this...

Here is the error am getting while build process..

[image]

Comment: Thank you for reply..
.Program 'runtests.cmd' failed to run: The system cannot find the file specifiedAt line:1 char:1 + . 'C:\agent\_work\1\s\ThinCUI\runtests.cmd' + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~. At line:1 char:1 + . 'C:\agent\_work\1\s\ThinCUI\runtests.cmd' + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed

Comment: There's no file called `runtests.cmd` in the directory `C:\agent\_work\1\s\ThinCUI`.